# PHP SESSION lost after updating by Ajax requests

Tags: php, ajax, session

I have a problem that I'm losing PHP Session somehow after I update last request time by Ajax when I'm typing in text editor. So basically idea is that when I'm using text editor on my website I want to update `$_SESSION['LAST_REQUEST']` variable to the current time and in the core of the web I'm doing check if the $_SESSION['LAST_REQUEST'] isn't exceeding 15 minutes. If it is then I end Session.
So here you can see how I check Session:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_REQUEST']) && ((time() - $_SESSION['LAST_REQUEST']) > 60 * 15))
{
    $_SESSION['sessionExpired'] = true;
    header('Location: sessionExpired.php'); 
}
```

And here is the ajax called page script which updates `$_SESSION['LAST_REQUEST']` variable

```
if (isset($_POST['inactive_session']) && !empty($_POST['inactive_session']))
{   
    // Renew session data
    $_SESSION['LAST_REQUEST'] = time();
}
```

Basically when I type few times everything is ok, but when I type  fast and many then the sessions has been lost..

P.S.
This is javascript code from where I make requests to update session from tinymce editor.

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    theme: "modern",
    browser_spellcheck: true,
    resize : "both",
    height: 200,
    autoresize_min_height: 200,
    plugins: [
        "hr pagebreak spellchecker wordcount code table paste textcolor"
    ],
    toolbar: "forecolor backcolor",
    setup : function(ed) {
        ed.on("keyup", function(ed, e) {
            // updating session
            $.post("setSession.php", { inactive_session: new Date().getTime() });
        })
    }   
});
```

Comment: did you get any error when you add session start on ajax page, if session start is not written for current script it will work or it will trows an error "Session already start"

Comment: Show your javascript.

Comment: I've added javascript code

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase the time of expiration:

```
ini_set ( ' session.gc_maxlifetime ', 2 * 60 * 60); // 2 hours
```

Comment: Make sure you have permission to change the value

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `session_start();` at the top of your ajax page e.g.

```
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['inactive_session']) && !empty($_POST['inactive_session']))
{   
    // Renew session data
    $_SESSION['LAST_REQUEST'] = time();
}
```

`session_start()` must be called on every php page individually to take part of the same session.

Comment: Session is called on every request by other included page. Just checked

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that most browsers have a max concurrent ajax connection limit of 6 requests. Might it be possible that some of your rapid requests are simply being lost?

Comment: hmm maybe, then how can I overcome it?

Comment: Keep track of the number of active requests from the current page, and then disable your button/form when it comes to (or close to) 6. Then on the ajax success callback decrease the number again and reactivate your button/form.

Answer (score 0):

If PHP session is not helping for you then, you can save the session data into the database for that particular call in serialize form and check if session is lost or not on that file (where ever you check the session). This is just a workaround for your problem but this can be a solution, because most for the big frameworks uses Db to store their session value to overcome such situations. Hope this will help you